# Python for loop in the lambda to create 100 x[i]

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, lambda

In my code I need to create a lambda to realize a*x1+~~~~~~z*x100, in which a,~~z, are known parameters. I need to put a for loop inside a lambda expression, to realize such function:

```
x = lambda x: 5*x[0]+20*x[1]+~~~~~~21*x[99]
```

I wonder, if number of my variables are 1 million, how to realize it? I do not know how to make it happen. Please help, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean `sum(i*j for i, j in zip(coef, x))` where `coef` is list of your known parameters?

Comment: While other answers have given you various valid approaches, you should understand that you **never need** to create a lambda function. Indeed, if you are simply going to assign to a name, i.e. `x = lambda ...` then **you shouldn't be using lambda to begin with**.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass both the parameters, you could make a lambda to accept both lists, like so:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = [6,7,8,9,0]

sum_of_products = lambda _a,_x: sum(y*z for y, z in zip(_a, _x))

print(sum_of_products(a,x))
```

> `80`

#### Alternatively, and preferably you can also just define a normal function for this as well, and achieve the same results.:

```
def sum_of_products(a, x):
    return sum(y*z for y, z in zip(a, x))
```

Once you've written the function, you can also pass it around just like a lambda, so if you were going to assign it to a variable to begin with, it might be easier to read if you just `def` your function in the normal way.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
x = [6,7,8,9,0]

def sum_of_products(_a, _x):
    return sum(y*z for y, z in zip(_a, _x))

my_function = sum_of_products

print(my_function(a, x))
```

> `80`

Comment: Note, it is worth mentioning that it is explicitly against PEP8 style guidelines to assign a lambda to a name. The *only* utility of a lambda function compared to a function definition statement is that a lambda is anonymous. If you assign it to a name, that defeats it's singular purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
lambda x: sum(a * b for a, b in zip(x, [5, 20, ..., 21]))
```